# VMWARE Seperated Snapshot Disk disk files will now not work

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, snapshot

I have ended up with a stange problem where I have moved a Virtual Disk file across to another data store as the snapshots filled up the existing datastore to the extent that the VM failed to boot.

I am now in a scenario where the Virtual Disk fails to boot stating the message "The Parent of this virtual disk could not be opened" I can not download or move the location as it bugs out. Is there away I can restore or flaten a Virtual disk file in our example it is called "bird-serve-000002.vmkd"

any advice or guidence is appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Andrew.

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each snapshot file is two actual files: one small .vmdk and one larger -delta.vmdk. The plain .vmdk is a text file. If you open that file, you will find that it has a path to it's parent file - this is the link that has been broken. You'll have to readjust the links to point to the parent (wherever it went) to get it to work again.

Once you've done that, you can flatten or Storage vMotion any of the disk files around. Just don't move them manually, or you'll break the links again!

Comment: Thanks, I had deleted the small .vmdk files not realising what they were recreated them to point to each others CID and worked a charm again. Thank you.